# CHKDSK fails in Windows 10 but ok in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk

I have an old SSHD (Hybrid) 2.5" drive from my old Macbook which I wanted to reuse. So I decided to backup its NTFS volumes on Windows 10 Home but when I mounted it complained that it needed to check it. It claimed to fix some things but then it failed with bad clusters. Here is an event log entry from when I run `CHKDSK` from the command prompt...

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on J:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is BOOTCAMP.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

  264448 file records processed.                                                         
  File verification completed.

  752 large file records processed.                                                                                                                           

  0 bad file records processed. 

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

  350480 index entries processed. 
  Index verification completed.

  0 unindexed file scanned.                                                                                                                                
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.  

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.

  43017 data files processed. 
  CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...

  34381512 USN bytes processed.                                                            
  Usn Journal verification completed.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Read failure with status 0xc000000e at offset 0x1327ca000 for 0x10000 bytes.

A disk read error occurredc000000e
Read failure with status 0xc000000e at offset 0xc091bc00 for 0x400 bytes.
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 29000 of name .

An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e af6).
Write failure with status 0xc000000e at offset 0xc0f99800 for 0x400 bytes.
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 1583).
```

But in Windows 7 Pro the same volume passes,

```
C:\>chkdsk /f  /r /x /b e:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is BOOTCAMP.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
  264448 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  752 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  2 EA records processed.
  52 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
  350482 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)...
  264448 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  43018 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  34312864 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
  264432 files processed.
File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  21187048 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the
master file table (MFT) bitmap.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system.

 195442687 KB total disk space.
 110207832 KB in 206505 files.
    115224 KB in 43019 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    371435 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  84748196 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  48860671 total allocation units on disk.
  21187049 allocation units available on disk.
```

After passing `CHKDSK` in W7pro I put it back on the W10 machine and the same errors again! W10 seems to be able to see the volumes and mounts them but why is `CHKDSK` seeing problems?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.